# shell method rolving twice

Tags: calculus, volume

let A is the region enclosed by $x=1, y=1, y=1-x$. then suppose S is the solid obtained by revolving A about y-axis. Find volume of soild obtained by revolving S about the x-axis.

I've used shell method for revolving once, and I can't imagine how to calculate twice revolving.

I know volume of A is $2\pi \int_0^1 x(1-x)\,dx$.

p.s. if I want to get surface of area S, same method for calculating volume works?

Comment: I think $dy$ makes more sense for volume if you want to use shells $$V = 2\pi\int\limits_0^1 y(1-(1-y))~ dy =2\pi\int\limits_0^1 y^2~ dy $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your region is a right triangle. Revolving it around $y$ gives a cylinder with a cone taken out of it.  Your first volume integral is not correct as the height at $x$ is not $1-x$ but $x$-the triangle is above $y=1-x$, not below it.  The volume is then $2\pi\int_0^1xydx=2\pi\int_0^1x^2dx$

Having made that shape, to revolve it around the $x$ axis it seems washers are the way to go.  For each bit of $dx$ you need to figure out the range in $y$ that the shape covers.  My imagination is failing me-I would make  model out of paper to help.

To get the surface area, remember you have to integrate arc length of the original surface.